# Could not create type 'XXXX.BaseWebserver'

Tags: c#, web-services

I tried to browse my web service with chrome but it throws error like Could not create type 'XXXX.BaseWebserver'.

**CODE**

```
      using System.Data;
      using System.Web;
      using System.Collections;
      using System.Web.Services;
      using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
      using System.ComponentModel;

      namespace Vitb.Maid.Services.Endpoints
      {
           /// <summary>
          /// Summary description for BaseWebserver
         /// </summary>
         [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
         [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
         [ToolboxItem(false)]
         public class BaseWebService : WebService
         {

                  public AuthenticationSoapHeader AuthenticationHeader;
         }


       }
```

**ERROR**

```
       Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="BaseWebService.asmx.cs" 
       Class="XXXXX.BaseWebserver" %>
```

Please help . Any clue to solve this issue .

Comment: The clue is to say goodbye to asmx based web service. Nobody should use it any more, and then such problems will never happen again.

Comment: I know but still my project uses it and I have to repair it . what can i say coding is headache :- (

Comment: Then you forgot to make it an application on IIS. Merely a virtual directory won't be able to host your web app, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis